# Assign a category, according to range of the value as a new column, python

Tags: python, r, pandas, range, categories

I have a piece of R code that i am trying to figure out how to do in Python pandas.
It takes a column called INDUST_CODE and **check its value to assign a category according to range of the value as a new column.** May i ask how i can do something like that in python please?

```
  industry_index <- full_table_update %>%
      mutate(industry = case_when(
        INDUST_CODE < 1000 ~ 'Military_service',
        INDUST_CODE < 1500 & INDUST_CODE >= 1000 ~ 'Public_service',
        INDUST_CODE < 2000 & INDUST_CODE >= 1500 ~ 'Private_sector',
        INDUST_CODE >= 2000 ~ 'Others'
        )) %>%
      select(industry)
```

Comment: In R, I would usually use `cut` to do this without having to type out each and every range - `cut(x, c(-Inf,1000,1500,2000,Inf), labels=c("a","b","c","d"))`. So in Python i'd look for a cut function too - this looks promising - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pandas.cut` to organise this into bins in line with your example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([500, 1000, 1001, 1560, 1500, 2000, 2300, 7, 1499], columns=['INDUST_CODE'])

   INDUST_CODE
0          500
1         1000
2         1001
3         1560
4         1500
5         2000
6         2300
7            7
8         1499

df['Categories'] = pd.cut(df['INDUST_CODE'], [0, 999, 1499, 1999, 100000], labels=['Military_service', 'Public_service', 'Private_sector', 'Others'])

   INDUST_CODE        Categories
0          500  Military_service
1         1000    Public_service
2         1001    Public_service
3         1560    Private_sector
4         1500    Private_sector
5         2000            Others
6         2300            Others
7            7  Military_service
8         1499    Public_service
Categories (4, object): [Military_service < Public_service < Private_sector < Others]
```

Comment: Nearly identical to R's cut function, there you go!